# AWS: Where to find a API Gateway custom authoriser's ID?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Im building a serverless backend for my project using the following AWS technologies:

- Lambda, implemented the python framework [Chalice](https://github.com/awslabs/chalice)
- API gateway
- Cognito

I have created a custom authoriser that intercepts all API calls and validates authorisation. I want to connect a view function to the authoriser. According to [documentation](https://github.com/awslabs/chalice#custom-auth-handler) this is done the following way:

```
@app.route('/authenticated', methods=['GET'], authorization_type='CUSTOM', authorizer_id='ab12cd')
def authenticated():
    return {"secure": True}
```

**Question:** Where can I find my authorisers id?

The following image is the only information I have about my custom authoriser from the API Gateway console:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of searching, I finally found the answer. The ID is located at in the "breadcrumbs" on the console. I've censored the actual ID out, but you get the idea.

[image]